# Notepad switches

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, notepad

What command line switches exist for Notepad?

I found a few:

```
/A <filename> opens file as ANSI
/W <filename> opens file as Unicode
/P <filename> prints filename
```

Are there others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Source of below info](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Q_21246332.html):

> ...command line arguments notepad takes
>
> `/A <filename>` open file as ansi
> `/W <filename>` open file as unicode
> `/P <filename>` print filename
> `/PT <filename> <printername> <driverdll> <port>`
> `/.SETUP` some weird stuff is happening i cant identify...

Comment: -1 for even mentioning the hyphened site! How dare you? (Joking)

Comment: Judging by this page:
http://www.spic.net/hplx/windows/win3.0/disk1/setup.inf
the /.setup switch was used during the automated setup of verrry old versions of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

`/S` suppresses the file-not-found prompt (you still get another prompt).

You can also use CMD.exe to control window size (and pipe input):

`cmd.exe /c start /max notepad.exe c:/temp/toto.txt`